# JDBC query insert with special character ("\N", "\S" and "\T")

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, special-characters

I have raw insert query like

```
insert into sample(id, name) values(1, 'text \\N\');
```

Getting `SqlException` while trying to insert via jdbc but the same insert query is working if I insert via mysql command prompt(console).

jdbc insert query is failing due to special characters("\N") in name field.

so how to overcome and insert the name with \N?

Comment: Which DB do you use?

Comment: why you have extra "\" after "\\N"?

Comment: I use mysql database

Comment: @Nawnit Sen: for some reason I am receiving name with \\N\ so my part is to process without any modification

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan can you add the complete error message? And try "\\N\\" this might work

Comment: Are you trying to insert a string value that contains the newline character (U+000A) or are you trying to insert a string value that contains the two characters `\N` ?

Comment: @ Gord Thompson I am trying to insert \N as part of name field

Comment: Please post your actual code and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: "I am receiving name with \\N\" - So you already have the desired string value in a Java `String` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest approach is to not use a raw SQL query at all. If, as you've stated, you receive the name from some other process then it is presumably in a `String` variable (or property, or similar) so you can simply use a *parameterized query* to perform the insert:

```java
// example data
int theId = 1;
String theName = "the name you received from somewhere else";
//
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sample (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.setInt(1, theId);
ps.setString(2, theName);
ps.executeUpdate();
```